# Stream: mix Write and WriteAsync in a single procedure

Tags: c#, async-await, stream

I'm trying to rewrite some old code with async/await concept.

Consider the next simplified code:

```
public async Task<bool> Foo()
{
   using (var stream = new Stream()); // Any stream allowing async operations
   ....
   stream.Write(0xff);
   var bytes = new byte[];
   // fill bytes
   await stream.WriteAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
   ....
   stream.Write(0xff);
   // refill bytes
   await stream.WriteAsync(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
   ....
   await stream.FlushAsync();
}
```

So my question: Is it safe to mix `Write` and `WriteAsync` calls in the same procedure? What pitfalls can be here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: i think it be safe cause you use await and it main if writeAsync done go next line.

Comment: Yes, it's safe if `WriteAsync` is completed before you call `Write`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method is safe in that, in isolation, it will behave as you intend: each `Write` / `WriteAsync` will occur sequentially, because the async writes are being awaited.

This being said, from the callers perspective, it is far from ideal to mix sync and async in the implementation.

The caller, seeing an async method, would (rightly) assume that it is non-blocking.

This isn't the case, because `Foo` executes synchronously up until the first `await`, which would block the calling thread for that duration.

There are situations where an async method must run some expensive CPU-code before the async work, but this is not one of those; it would be preferable to use `WriteAsync` for every write.

Comment: but in this case of the single byte, is it worth the extra memory/array allocation to push the byte into and the two sequential async calls?